# Please correct the path for Joomla Javascript Async and Defer plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, javascript, fix-my-code

Hello i want to Defer parsing of JavaScript of the following link in joomla by using Javascript Async and Defer plugin.

http://www.domain.com/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/gz/1/0/83c44f52555d09b338538d6e78c2a63d.js

But when i insert the path 
/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/gz/1/0/83c44f52555d09b338538d6e78c2a63d.js

The plugin shows the following error

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/iglobez3/public_html/domain.com/plugins/system/sr2win/sr2win.php on line 99

Please guide me with the correct path. i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: When you insert the path? JCH Ooptimize allows you to defer JS as an option if I rightly remember. As for the error, I don't think that path has anything to do with the JCH Optimize plugin. Please Google this error as you will find an answer on Stack Overflow instantly

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am getting error on (Javascript Async and Defer) joomla plugin. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/javascript-async-and-defer

Comment: As mentioned before, please Google this error. I have no idea what code you're using so you cannot help

Answer (score 1):

In the file `sr2win.php`, on line 99, you have a reference assignment that you need to get rid of. Most likely, you will just need to remove the ampersand (&) from that file from that line.

If you are on a production environment, you should also disable error reporting by setting the error reporting in the global configuration settings to "None".